# How to call sub controller from main controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I have main controller.

Controller Folder: main.php

the usual coding is you will call everything from main controller.

```
class Main extends CI_Controller{
  public function index(){
  //line of codes
  }
  public function login(){
  //line of codes
  }
  public function register(){
  //line of codes
  }
}
```

So instead of doing this, I'm thinking to make login and register as sub controller and call them from the main controller but I don't know how to call them.

Controller folder: main.php, login.php, register.php

Please paste some line of code and if you can explain it as well.

Comment: It would be better practice to setup your login and register functions within a model. You could then load this model from any controller and call the functions as needed.

Comment: My main idea is have sub controller and include or call them into main controller, so that, whenever i have a problem I don't need to scroll and look a thousand line of codes to check only for 1 error which is in example in login. I think putting the login function within the model is not proper for coding and it destroy the idea of MVC.

Comment: Actually what you're suggesting is an incorrect implementation of MVC. If you have a function that you want to use more than once, especially if it interacts with a database in anyway. You should put it in a model.

Comment: The one I'm thinking is, instead of putting a bunch of code for login or register into main controller, I want to separate it, so that it will be easy to check errors. Regarding the interactions for the database, yes I will used Model for DB only and it doesn't include any functions and calling pages that needs to be send to View. The Sub Controller will the one to call the Model and send data and functions, etc to View. Thanks for the comment and suggestion. More suggestion is so much appreciated.

Comment: I am really confused now. What EXACTLY are you trying to use in multiple places?

Comment: to lessen the line of code from main controller and to trace error easily.

Comment: oh i found this one http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/55212/ similar with what i'm trying to do but don't give any code though.

Comment: I think I found the answer to what I want to do. It's HMVC.